# WPF CheckedListBox EF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox, listbox

I know this is probably really daft, but my head isn't working properly today.

I have a patient entity and a disability table. A patient can have 0 or many disabilities.

If I create a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `Disability` how do I hook the checked/unchecked of the items `CheckBox` to add/remove the disability from my patients' collection of Disabilities using MVVM? What would the `CheckBox` be bound to on my patient entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CheckedListBox` expects to be bound to a list of items that have a boolean property which indicates the state of each checkbox. However, your model has a collection property that you wish to add / remove items to / from based on the checkbox state.

This sounds like the job of a view model!

From your `PatientViewModel` expose a collection of `DisabilityViewModel` instances that are bound to your `CheckedListBox`, each `DisabilityViewModel` instance should have a `IsChecked` boolean property. Detect the changing of this state within your view model, then within `PatientViewModel` updated the state of the wrapped `Patient` model object.